# ANDROID: After Rename .IML all Classes Red and Project won't Build

Tags: android, android-studio, build, android-manifest, naming

[image]

I was following a youtube tutorial on changing my android studio project name, so that when I download it from Google Play it doesn't display the old app name. The video suggested Refactor--> Renaming the .IML file, and then going to Modules.xml and changing the values there. Now my project won't build and all my classes have a red "J" on them and they're all grayed out. Please help!!!

Comment: Delete the iml files and the .idea folder, then rebuild the project with gradle

Comment: IML files? Or File? I deleted the .IML file and the .idea folder, rebuilt with gradle and I still have the same problem. I've been working on this project for months, this is a disaster...

Comment: if you have renamed the folder, check also the settings.gradle file. It should contain the renamed folder.

Comment: There is nothing in the settings.gradle file, nothing at all

Comment: Check the updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a structure like this:

```
root
  .idea            //remove it
  mymodule
     mymodule.iml  //remove it
     build.gradle
     src
  project.iml      //remove it
  build.gradle
  settings.gradle
```

Follow these steps:

- Remove the iml file in each module
- Remove the .idea folder

Open the `settings.gradle` file and check if it is somenthing like:

```
   include ':mymodule'
```

where mymodule is the name of the folder which contains the module (`build.gradle` and code)

- resync and rebuild the project

Comment: Each module meaning the module.xml file? Could you specify where I would find "each" module? Not super familiar with the inner workings of the IDE. I tried opening the module.xml file and removing the .IML references listed. Then deleted the .idea folder, then opened up settings.gradle and there was nothing in the file. So I added ':mymodule' to it, then it made a folder that now contains a 'mymodule.iml' but I've still got X's through my entire project... I'm screwed...

Comment: @Professor_Membrane check the updated answer. Of course use your current name for the mymodule.